# Switch between divs while scrolling, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a portfolio page.
Technologies I am using are HTML, CSS and jQuery.
However, I am stuck at a problem involving scrolling my page up and down. U see, while I scroll down, I want to add a class on the navbar link, corresponding to the div I am on the page. While it happens, to some extent, while scrolling down, it just messes up while scrolling up.

Following is my code ..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(".navbar-links").click(function(){
    $(".navbar-links").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
  
  var portfolio_offset = $("#portfolio-section").offset().top;
  
  var about_offset = $("#about-section").offset().top;
  
  var contact_offset = $("#contact-section").offset().top;
  
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".navbar-links").removeClass("active");
    //var scrolled_offset = window.pageYOffset;
    var scrolled_offset = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrolled_offset>=contact_offset)
      {
        $("#contact_link").addClass("active");
      }
    else if(scrolled_offset>=portfolio_offset)
      {
        $("#portfolio_link").addClass("active");
      }
    else
      {
        $("#about_link").addClass("active");
      }
  });
  
  $("button").click(function(){
    window.open($(this).val(),"_blank"); 
  });
  
});
```

```css
button {
  background : transparent;
  border : 1px solid white;
  padding : 0px;
  margin : 10px;
}

i {
  border : 0px;
}

#about-section {
  background-color : #fd746c;
  color : black;
}

#portfolio-section {
  background-color : #904e95;
  color : black;
}

#contact-section {
  background-color : #4ca1af;
  color : black;
}

.active {
  border : 1px solid white;
}

#navbar-menu {
  text-align : center;
}

.heading {
  font-family : Sofia;
}

.navbar {
  background-color : black;
}

.content {
  font-family : Lily Script One;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size : 27px;
}

.content-div {
  text-align : center;
  display : inline-block;
  vertical-align : middle;
  float : none;
}

.navbar-links {
  font-size : 20px;
}

.center {
  text-align : center;
}

img {
  border : 1px solid white;
  margin : auto;
  top : 0;
  left : 0;
  right : 0;
  bottom : 0;
}

.project-img {
  max-width : 70%;
  max-height : 70%;
}

.fa {
  padding : 20px;
  font-size : 45px;
  width : 100px;
  text-align : center;
  text-decoration : none;
  background : #2c4762;
  color: white;
  margin : 0px 0px;
  border : 1px solid white;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity : 0.7;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="navbar-section">
      <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
        <div class="navbar-header heading">
          <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span></button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Portfolio Page</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right heading">
            <li class="navbar-links active" id="about_link"><a href="#about-section">About</a><li>
            <li class="navbar-links" id="portfolio_link"><a href="#portfolio-section">Portfolio</a><li>
            <li class="navbar-links"><a href="#contact-section" id="contact_link">Contact</a><li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid" id="scrollable-div">
  <div class="row" id="about-section">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="center heading">
      <h1>About</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 content-div content">
          <h3>Rishabh Kashyap</h3>
          <h3>Full Stack Web Developer</h3>
          <h3>Key Interests - JavaScript & MEAN Stack</h3>
          <h3>Worked as an intern @ Sapient Global Markets</h3>
          <h4><i>"Never be afraid to take risks. If you succeed, you can lead and if you fail, you can guide."</i><h4>
          <h4>- Swami Vivekananda</h4>
          <h3>Indeed. The motto, I try to live by. Professionally, as well as, Personally.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 content-div">
          <img class="img-responsive project-img" alt="my image" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/34CJNU0DexpintEhsM5-zcZdT_7mRWVA6dE-7f122WM3xj4xFI0nXYQhXyEG8tyrd4piHPHPGtCNtu_o5vqZ2eFFH2W9YS4ekKCqw7wgZzAjsKD8hdNoV5DrARz7I-BRljjksmdfHxoHaGIgwxcNYRJkEBa2FLIhbluVGZo1qN3zZ1ZJ1WpRU27mBbrCScNzazuOFtY0lOBX4JAKd7yGlC7ILwg4gAy-KsN-ZJz54PoNeCblgrz3jGsF8YvEf5Hc-V3kV8DtrDiKiwTpXPowvrLdldS-rIlOpjq1LrbPVNxWUNB1YieiqOUo1AEVYaS9WxiIFae2etL7Jb4nAW9MkLHE-YvQZ4VVcntRfXS3CBnuoy6EPHu2vfevnNeK9lgANs4rb1MNyMCxOACWmn45_vZKZoPfnmk_cyVzt7m2vFZUXPMdyeSRrViQD9VteriL89XHZlItrlgIhXI1vt5JAASHdOYrNV3CTpWMGPfzQk0BfQbbr2qcxnbgbSyEmK4M1wIloFQ0O_q-MCOdffySKCmct8iHRRrAcG5cWF_ArcX5GptL3tHAQHu9UCyfrjwIyI28NbrgZM0NkxxmpRAV5nRJGQetgxewxGaS2A6xfWnlW8jP-P4z=w479-h638-no?.jpg"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="portfolio-section">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="center heading">
      <h1>Portfolio</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
      <img class="img-responsive project-img" alt="portfolio page" src="http://www.thefamouspeople.com/profiles/images/swami-vivekananda-3.jpg"/>
      <h4><i>A tribute page to Swami Vivekananda using basic HTML & Bootstrap.</i></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="contact-section">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="center heading">
      <h1>Contact Me</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
      <div class="center content">
        <h4><i>rishabhkashyap.rk@gmail.com</i></h4>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="center">
        <button value="https://www.facebook.com/rishabh.kashyap.940436"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></button>
        <button value="https://twitter.com/iamrkcheers"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></button>
        <button value="https://github.com/iamrkcheers"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></button>
        <button value="https://www.freecodecamp.com/iamrkcheers"><i class="fa fa-free-code-camp"></i></button>
        <button value="https://www.linkedin.com/in/rishabh-kashyap-735879117/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="meta-section">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my link for the code ..
https://codepen.io/iamrkcheers/pen/KmxEpw

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `#contact_link` is on your a `href` instead of your list item, so the `.active` will not be set on `.navbar-links`.

Comment: U sir, are a life saviour !
Thanks a ton.